# Global constants in a static library are nil at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a static library which contains some constants such as:

```
    // constants.h
    NSString* const KDefaultProtocol;

    // constants.m
    NSString* const kDefaultProtocol = @"https";

    // OtherCode.m
     NSString *s = kDefaultProtocol;
```

When I run an app which links to the library the value of kDefaultProtocol is nil. Why is that?

(constants.m is included in the library compile sources section).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// constants.h
NSString* const KDefaultProtocol;
```

This one is incorrect. You meant:

```
// constants.h
extern NSString* const KDefaultProtocol;
```

The reason you're not getting the warning you should is because you've used mismatched the case of the leading `K` (which raises the question of how `OtherCode.m` even compiles; I suspect this is not exactly the code in question).

Answer (score 0):

Try it->

```
// constants.h
static NSString * const KDefaultProtocol = @"https";
```